# Pear Authentication

Tags: php, hash, authentication, pear

Has anyone ever tried to use SHA-256 or SHA-512 with PEAR AUTH?
MD5 works perfectly however, nothing happens when you set the cryptType  to

'cryptType' => 'sha256'

The page will just reload. I'm using MDB2 With this.

Code is here: http://pastie.org/1065896

Comment: Anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Please post some code.  It's hard to tell exactly what you're talking about without some context.  Further, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I've posted the code here: http://pastie.org/1065896

Comment: @john: Thanks.  Can we also get the output of either `DESCRIBE auth` or `SHOW CREATE TABLE auth` from MySQL?  And your PHP version.

Comment: its php5 and...username is varchar(50) and password varchar(32)

does password need to be 64 to use sha256?

Comment: 5?  5.0?  5.1?  5.2?  5.3?  It matters, sometimes!  Though not in this case anymore.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table's `password` field has a length restriction that's cutting off the hash.

```
php > echo hash('md5', 'Your face is on fire.');
93d4258aa007d4346197b2f0433397f6
```

MD5 is 32 characters.

```
php > echo hash('sha1', 'Your face is on fire.');
19cc616238440e31065d97ec9f77d89ff319272b
```

SHA1 is 40.

```
php > echo hash('sha256', 'Your face is on fire.');
d9eb62abf8a261958ada70e59e492f2ef65b06527a2040123d69f9e59046b843
```

SHA2 256 is 64.

```
php > echo hash('sha512', 'Your face is on fire.');
38b0ef9577cfda32edda324f3c70cacebfdb304125e439c17aa6f5d41ed091a515ddc9800c58e67a48b85874f349e886cc6f506fc159086d086a500fe4bc8fc8
```

And SHA2 512 breaks the trend and goes all the way up to 192 characters.

One of MySQL's failings is that it will let this happen and only issue a warning instead of stopping cold and telling you that you're trying to put ten pounds of data in a one pound bag.